# How to change color of a table row based on object property value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects as output from API as below:

```js
var x = [{
    name: "test",
    group: [{
      name: "rating",
      value: "55"
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "test1",
    group: [{
      name: "rating",
      value: "20"
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    group: [{
      name: "rating",
      value: "60"
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "test3",
    group: [{
      name: "rating",
      value: "10"
    }]
  }
]
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test2</td>
    <td>test3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to change the color of all the rows of the table to green based on the object value `x.group[0].value` greater than 30. Any idea how can I achieve this? I am trying to group the arrays with the values greater than 30 but I am not sure how can I change color based on that.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].group[0].value
}
```

**Note: I am using ReactJS. I created a Table component like  [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/pagination?file=/src/App.js). I am not sure if I can change HTML much**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a condition to determine whether or not `x.group[0].value` is bigger than `30`

```
<table>
    <tr style={{backgroundColor: !!(x.group[0].value > 30) ? 'green': 'red'}}>test</tr>
    <tr style={{backgroundColor: !!(x.group[0].value > 30) ? 'green': 'red'}}>test1</tr>
    <tr style={{backgroundColor: !!(x.group[0].value > 30) ? 'green': 'red'}}>test2</tr>
    <tr style={{backgroundColor: !!(x.group[0].value > 30) ? 'green': 'red'}}>test3</tr>
</table>
```

Adding this line `style={{ backgroundColor: !!true ? "green" : "red" }}` to line 101 inside the  tag in your code example makes the table rows green. Change the condition to use your value, and it'd be green/*your color* depending on the condition

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `clsx` library with which you can provide multiple `className`s conditionally.

```
<tr
  className={clsx({
    defaultClass: true,
    tableGreen: x.group[0].value > 30,
    // other conditional classes
  })}
>
  ...
</tr>
```

In your `styles.css`

```css
.defaultClass {
  padding: 5px;
}

.tableGreen {
  backgroundColor: #00ff00;
}
```

For it to work with `react-table` you will have to modify the the array structure

```js
function transform(y) {
  return y.map((i) => ({
    name: i.name,
    ...i.group.reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, [curr.name]: curr.value }), {}),
  }));
}
```

It will give you output like this

```json
[
    {
        "name": "test",
        "rating": "55"
    },
    {
        "name": "test1",
        "rating": "20"
    },
    {
        "name": "test2",
        "rating": "60"
    },
    {
        "name": "test3",
        "rating": "10"
    }
]
```

When comparing, make sure to convert the `rating` into a `number` type using `parseInt`. Eventually in the `Table` component as in the example you provided.

```
<tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
  {page.map((row, i) => {
    prepareRow(row);
    return (
      <tr
        {...row.getRowProps()}
        className={clsx({
          defaultClass: true,
          tableGreen: parseInt(row.original.rating) > 30,
          // other conditional classes
        })}
      >
        {row.cells.map((cell) => {
          return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
        })}
      </tr>
    );
  })}
</tbody>
```